# Adding a Static ip device to my network

Tags: networking, ip, network-adapter

I have a new machine that's added to my network.
It has a IP that cant be changed.
IP `10.47.101.10     255.255.255`.
My network is `192.168.0.1 - 200`.

I cant for the life of me figure out how to connect the two.
When I change my computers IP to `10.47.101.x` I can ping the new device.

Comment: You can add this address to Your station instead of change (it will have 2 addresses). Open Your Network Connection properties, open Ipv4 component properties, press Additionally knob and add this address to the Addresses window. You must repeat it on each station which need to communicate with new device.

Comment: Is this an XY Problem? Why can’t the IP address be changed?

Comment: the  new device is connected to another network. it has 2 ports  that has the same config, 1 port is used for Engine Controller, the other one is remote controll.

Comment: I'm confused... You can't change the IP address of either interface? If it is integrated into one network and has a 2nd interface, it has to have a different IP address, why can't you change that one? As Appleoddity said, I think this is an XY problem and you are trying to "fix" the wrong issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a network that consists of several different segments (10.47.101.0-255 and 192.168.0.1-200), add proper routing rules to all parts of the network where this matters (in other words, where the default route would go wrong).

As you have given no details about your network setup, I can't tell you which parts that would be.

As you have given no details about the OS in your computer(s) and the kind of router(s) you are using, I can't tell you how to set the routes.

(I also recommend to read up on some networking basics, so you have a better idea what routing is, and why it is required here.).